# 「ばかりに」についての文法の質問です。教えてください

Tags: grammar

> 子供に歯磨きの習慣をつけさせたい**ばかりに**、親がストレスを感じても**よくありません**。

why is it 良くありません　instead of よくあります。

「ばかりに」の意味は「のせいで」と同じだ思ってたから、この文の後ろには、否定形の方は正しくないと思います。

一応こういう例文から参照してる。

> お金がない**ばかりに**、今度の旅行には行けなかったのです。

教えてください。

Comment: Did you by any chance take 「よくありません」 to mean 'does not happen often'? It actually means 'is not good' in this case.  It's a polite negative form of よい('good') and not よく('often') + polite negative form of ある('be' or 'happen').

Comment: snailboatさん、整然と色をつけてくれて、ありがとう！

Comment: @goldbrick Yes, I mistakenly interpreted it that way. (A really serious mistake for someone who is preparing for N1 level, I am such a shame to the Japanese language learner community lol) Anyway, thanks for pointing that out clearly!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> 「子供に歯磨きの習慣をつけさせたいばかりに、親がストレスを感じてもよくありません。」

このセンテンスは、文法的にも、意味的にも特に問題はありません。

「ばかりに」の意味を、質問者さんは少し勘違いされているように、私には見受けられます。「ばかりに」の意味は単純に「のせいで」ということではないのです。（両者に意味上の共通点はありますが。）

「ばかりに」のより正確な意味は、「それだけの理由で」または「それだけの**ほんの小さな**原因で」というものになります。「ちょっとした理由・原因で予想をしていなかったネガティブな結果になってしまう」という状況を表すのに使用される表現なのです。

従って、「ばかりに」の後に来るフレーズは**内容的にはネガティブなものになりますが、文法的には肯定・否定のどちらの形を取っていてもおかしくありません**。ここは重要な部分です。

上の例文に話を戻しますと、『子供に歯磨きの習慣をつけさせたい』というのは親なら誰もが持っているような願いです。その意図自体は善良なものですね。しかし、その親の願望が強過ぎる場合には、子供がそれに反抗したりして、歯磨きを嫌がったりもしますね。そうなると、親としてはストレスとして感じてしまうわけです。

善良な意図・目的をもって行う行動が、結果としてネガティブなものになってしまうのは良くないと言っているのです。「ばかりに」が正しく使われているセンテンスです。

ちなみに、「親がストレスを感じても**よくあります**」は意味の通じないフレーズです。

最後に、二番目の例文について一言。

> 「お金がないばかりに、今度の旅行には行けなかったのです。」

この文は、間違いであるとは言えないものの、私見ですが、特別に良い文ではないと思います。その理由は、「お金」は「旅行」にとって非常に重要な要素ですので、上述したように、決して「小さな理由」とは言えないからなんです。「ばかりに」よりは「ために」、「せいで」を使用したほうが良いかと思います。

Comment: さん、丁寧に教えてくださって、ありがとうございます。とても、わかりやすくて、すっかり書いてくださいました。読むとすぐ、理解できました！（ちなみに、私は、@l'électeurさんが書いてくださったわかりやすい説明文を書けるようになりたいな）頑張ります！

Answer (score 5):

**ばかりに** has the meaning of "only/solely/simply/wholly because of/due to/from" (context will help you decide which combination of word choices makes the most sense)

**よくありません** in this sentence is the polite form of **よくない** which means "not good"

So the writer is trying to communicate:

"It's **not good** for parents to stress out **simply from** trying to instill good tooth brushing habits in their children."

or more literally

"It's **not good** for parents to stress out **simply because** they want to instill good tooth brushing habits in their children."

Comment: Thank you very much! It is really helpful that you write the explanation in English. I think the nuance of this language is really beautiful.