# Just by: だけで vs ばかりに

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

I've been using Bunpro to review grammar and came across the following example sentence:

外国人だけど、着物を着る______、日本人みたいになった。

The site is looking for だけで (just by) as the answer, which I understand in hindsight. However, my initial answer was ばかりに.

Does this answer also make sense? If so, is there a difference in meaning   or connotation between the two?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are very different.

- `A だけで B`: *B just by/with/using A* (quite straightforward)

  - cf. `A だけに B`: *B, true to its (name, form, nature, reputation...) being A*
- `A(-u)ばかりに B`: *so much A that B [some ironical result]*

  - cf. `A(-ta)ばかりに B` *B [unexpected result] merely due to A*
  - cf. `A(-u)ばかりで`: *only to A; only keep doing A*

    - cf. `A ばかりで B`: usually a negative comment of the speaker in B, or a formula `B' しない` to say *do all times A and nothing B'*

So, only だけで makes sense here.

Further:

- [Meaning of “だけに”](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/54611/7810)
- [plain form + bakari vs. te form + bakari](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/65429/7810)
- [「ばかりに」についての文法の質問です。教えてください](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/59981/7810)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't make sense. Dictionaries say that ただそれだけの原因・理由で、事態が悪化するような結果が導かれることを表す. For example, 「ちょっと油断をしたばかりに、とんでもないことになってしまった」 「ちょっと口をすべらしたばかりに、すっかり怒らせてしまった」.

If the speaker doesn't like to be seen as a Japanese. 外国人だけど、着物を着**た**ばかりに、日本人みたいになった makes sense.